# Moving an iPad synced folder within my computer

Tags: ipad, ios9, itunes, rsync

I am new to iTunes and am getting familiarized with the new concepts.

I had synced a songs from my Windows to iPad. Then organized in the varies playlists. Now the folder I had already synced which is in Windows need to be moved another folder. When I do this, the iPad sync is failing as iTunes not finding the synced folder and all my music and playlist created are vanished.

Any workaround to re-sync the folder from new location and then re-store the created playlists?

Comment: Are you actually using the *nix utility `rsync` in some fashion here?

Comment: It sounds to me like this is not a programming question, and if so you're on the wrong site. You may find _Super User_ a better fit for this, if it is broadly about how to use iTunes.